# flutter ink well on tap not working in list wheel scroll view

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add ink well to List Wheel Scroll View in flutter but it is not working. Can you help me to add on tap in list wheel Scroll View

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Answer (score 0):

check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

Behavior:

When you click on the selected item, onItemTapCallback is called on the ClickableListWheelScrollView

When you click on another item, onItemTapCallback is called on the ClickableListWheelScrollView, immediately followed by a call to onSelectedItemChanged on the ListWheelScrollView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clickable_list_wheel_view/clickable_list_wheel_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'List Wheel',
          ),
        ),
        body: MyListWheel(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyListWheel extends StatelessWidget {
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();
  final double _itemHeight = 100.0;
  final data = List.generate(20, (index) => 'Item $index');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClickableListWheelScrollView(
      scrollController: _scrollController,
      itemHeight: _itemHeight,
      itemCount: data.length,
      onItemTapCallback: (index) {
        print("onItemTapCallback index: $index");
      },
      child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemExtent: _itemHeight,
        physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
        overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
        perspective: 0.002,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
          print("onSelectedItemChanged index: $index");
        },
        childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
          builder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text(data[index])),
          childCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome:) you can accept my answer and up vote it as appreaciation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest flutter.
Use ListTile onTap.
Its working for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).